# View Large image in a specified ImageView dimensions

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview, picasso

I have a large image of dimensions 1200x2400 . I was able to load that into an imageview using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) .  But I lost the quality of the image.

What I looking for is : In html you can specify `<img src ="img_Src" width="400" height="500">` where you can change width and height. Can we do something like that in android - loading the full image into a particular ImageView(say parent_with x parent_height) and zoom it so that you see the clear content inside it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the resize functionality that picasso supports

```
Picasso.with(this)
 .load("your image url")
 .resize(100, 100)
 .into(imageView)
```

Where resize(100,100) takes in width and height in dp (`resize(width,height)` is the general format)

Comment: Resizing is actually scaling down the image. when I zoom it, there is no quality.

Answer (score 0):

The stock ImageView does not support pinch zoom. Use a library such as [this one](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)  to give you a drop-in replacement that does support it.

However you are likely to run out of memory and crash when dealing with images that size, especially in the many common low to mid range phones out there.